# Yii2. How to abort controller/action with jquery?

Tags: jquery, yii2, action, abort

I have a ListView with pagination. How can I abort page change action with jquery?

I tried to do it with:

```
$(".pagination li a").click(function(){
    return;
});
```

But it does not work.

**EDIT:**
This works for me.

```
$(".pagination li a").click(function(){
        return false;
});
```

Comment: try prevent default `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution

```
$(".pagination li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Does not work. I just wrote return false; instead return; in my code example and it works.

Comment: OK..thats great but my code will work as preventDefault will stop the default behavior of the event.